# Get a value of php variable or constant inside mustache template?

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

`{{# info.products_image }}<div><img src="<?=IMAGES_PATH?>{{info.products_image}}" /></div>{{/ info.products_image }}`

Of course Mustache ignores short tag. How can I solve this problem?

Sure I can duplicate constants values within my object, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Why isn't it a good idea? You could use your own define function that defines it for PHP and for mustache

Comment: @Loïc, I have an IMAGES_PATH constant, and according to this logic, I have to use something like $this->imagesPath = IMAGES_PATH for my class, right? Are you sure it's a good idea? By the way, there are many other external vars I'd like to use in this template, should all of them be duplicated as class properties?